# reverse eating sounds

Tags: foley

so....firsty hello

secondly, i'm trying to create the sound a woman eating in reverse....literally pulling the food out of her mouth (intact)

i'm not getting quite enough "squish" when recording vocalizations....anyone have good advice on something to record for a nice wet squishing sound (i don't have much time to experiment myself)

it can be quite over the top and disgusting

thanks

john

Answer (score 5):

- **Watermelon**  - dig through it with your
  hands
- **raw chicken in marinade**  - awesome 'slimy guts' sounds
- **raw egg**  - for some more slimy goodness
- **hand soap**  - for the same
- **macaroni and cheese**  - for some smush
- **bread soaked in water**  - gives a nice
  fibrous squishy sound
- **bell peppers**  - rip them apart if you
  need some nice crunch

Grab your apron and get messy :) 
~Matt

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys,

I just saw this post and Matt listed some really good stuff.  I have created a fruits and vegetables bundle that you might want to check out.

https://getsoundeffects.com/#/products-page/sound-bundles/fruits-vegetables-collection/

I Hope this helps!

-Benjie

Answer (score 1):

I played with a cloth soaked in the mix of cat food, ketchup and banana. The smell was awful, but i got nice squishes (i layered some "thin" sounds to get one big and juicy).

Answer (score 1):

Along with the more specific squishes everyone else has recommended, I've had great success with a can of Hormel Chili. Open one end (fully remove lid), turn the can upside down, allow gravity to pull the contents out slowly onto a plate, bowl, or pan. Repack the can with the chili and go for take 2. The first take is usually the longest due to the canning process. Subsequent takes get shorter and shorter as more air is in the can when you pack it yourself. But you can get some nice, sloppy sounds that would be a great layer underneath the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

melons

thoughs squishy rubber toys filled with water at the toy store

Comment: Not to be gross, but have you considered actually recording someone vomiting? After all, that is literally "eating in reverse". :P

Answer (score 0):

try handling a soaking wet washcloth. you can get a lot of nice squishy sounds out those.